# How to get 0001 instead of 2001 using YYYY

Tags: business-objects, data-integration, sap-data-services

I have a column with different timestamps, like:

```
5771.10.04 16:07:23.800913000
0967.06.17 06:20:28.800906000
3857.06.18 03:49:03.800906000
01.04.29 16:45:04.400909000
```

I need to convert these into decimals (which I use for a join of some million rows), like so:

```
57711004160723800913
9670617062028800906
38570618034903800906
10429164504400909
```

I do it using this function:

```
cast(substr(to_char($timestamp,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF'),1,20), 'decimal(20,0)');
```

The problem is the last timestamp, which only has two digits for the year, where the YYYY conversion occurs. I would need the 01 to be transformed into 0001, instead it is transformed into 2001.

Any ideas how I could solve this in a quick/non-intensive way?

**Tl;dr** I need to transform the year 01 into 0001 instead of 2001 in BODS.

Comment: Put two zeros in front of the year?

Comment: How? Also, some of the timestamps I work with start with 4-digit-years, and some with 2-digit-years. And I want to make a join on this field, so too much fiddling with it would cost much time

Comment: I don't know much about BODS, but according to the [reference guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbods42/en/ds_42_reference_en.pdf), **rrrr** is not a valid date format specifier.

Comment: `regex_replace('01.04.29 16:45:04.400909000','[:. ]','')`  should replace the `:`, `.` and the space ` `, with the empty string `''`.